# Absolute position to container boostrap

Tags: html, css, containers, positioning, absolute

I'm having a trouble with properly aligning text to container. I need to put it into the position like on the picture, but text always going to the very right side of page.

[image]

Can you please help me with that ? Thank you!

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-text">
            <h3>My aligned heading</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 80px; 
    height: 518px;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;

    .container {

        .header-text {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 30px;

            h3 {
                font-weight: 400;
                font-size: 18px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 45px;
                border: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
                background-color: #fff;
                text-align: right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? do you want the text centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `position:relative;` to the `.container` instead of header. An absolutely positioned element is so to the first parent that is relative.